# GPU Power Profiling with nvprof and Visual Profiler

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010, cuda, profiling

I can see the power variations of my K20C through nvidia-smi as depicted below:

```
==============NVSMI LOG==============

Timestamp                           : Fri Jan 31 11:45:21 2014
Driver Version                      : 332.21

Attached GPUs                       : 2
GPU 0000:04:00.0
    Temperature
        Gpu                         : 28 C
    Power Readings
        Power Management            : Supported
        Power Draw                  : 16.12 W
        Power Limit                 : 225.00 W
        Default Power Limit         : 225.00 W
        Enforced Power Limit        : 225.00 W
        Min Power Limit             : 150.00 W
        Max Power Limit             : 225.00 W
```

I'm trying to profile GPU power during execution of my CUDA application. However, I cannot find where these numbers are reported in `Visual Profiler` or `nvprof`. According to CUDA Toolkit guide, I use the following command in `nvprof` to enable power profiling:

```
"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v5.5\bin\nvprof.exe" --print-gpu-trace --system-profiling on .\vectorAdd.exe
```

I also tried to retrieve the power profiling information from `Visual Profiler`. I check the `Enable power, clock, and  thermal profiling` box. However, I cannot see the power profile in the Timeline.

[image]

I'm using CUDA v5.5 on Windows 7 64-bit and the system GPU is K20c. I compile the CUDA application with Visual Studio 2010.

Any idea is highly appreciated.

Comment: The power profiling information is not available for all GPUs. You may wish to check if this is possible for your own card. In that case, run `nvidia-smi -q -d power`.

Comment: Power manager is available for K20C and `nvidia-smi -q -d POWER` reports the power for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Power profiling can be enabled:

1. On the second wizard page when creating a new session.
2. From the "Settings" view under the session timeline view.

Power profiling is not available for all devices and does not work on Mac OS X.

**Update from @ahmad:**

Oh, I found the problem. I was running win32 binary on 64-bit operating system. This is why the profilers do not report power, while every other profiling facilities work. Please add this issue to your answer, so we can mark this question answered. Thanks again.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As I mentioned in the question, I check these boxes to enable thermal and power profiling. But no luck! still no power profiling appears. Can you add a picture of Visual Profiler during a session that has reported power profile?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't make that picture at this time. You would see samples on the device row in the timeline view. One thing that I suspect happens to you is that your application is too short-lived for the sampling. Try performing more work in the device - e.g. call your CUDA code multiple times in a loop.

Comment: Yes, my application is very short. So now I'm testing `nbody` from CUDA Samples. But the profilers still do not report power consumption, even for 40 seconds of nbody.

Comment: Oh, I found the problem. I was running win32 binary on 64-bit operating system. This is why the profilers do not report power, while every other profiling facilities work. Please add this issue to your answer, so we can mark this question answered. Thanks again.

Comment: @ahmad Interesting. I'll send a link to profiler developers.